# Obtener post_id al publicar un mensaje en una página

Tags: facebook

Quisiera conseguir el post_id de una publicación que hago en una page de facebook de tal manera que mediante una url tipo https://www.facebook.com/xxxxx/posts/366453023551413 pudiera ir directamente a esa publicación

El código que utilizo para insertar el mensaje es el que pongo debajo. Lo que quisiera conseguir es el post_id que tendría el formato wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Con $graphNode['id'] siempre obtengo el mismo número y no me sirve para crear el enlace directo al mensaje insertado ya que siempre me envía a la página y no al mensaje concreto

He visto que mediante la API graph existe la forma de obtener ese número pero muestra todos los mensajes con su post_id.

```
$request = new FacebookRequest(
  $session,
  'GET',
  '/xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  array(
    'fields' => 'feed{id}'
  )
);

$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
/* handle the result */
```

¿Alguien podría indicarme que instrucción he de utilizar para para conseguirlo?

Un saludo y feliz año

---

El código que utilizo para insertar el mensaje es este:

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  'app_secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.6',
]);

$linkData = array(
 'message' => xxxxxxx,
 'picture' => 'http://www.xxxxxx.jpg',
 'link' => xxxxxx,
 'description' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
);

$pageAccessToken = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

$fb->setDefaultAccessToken($pageAccessToken);
try {
  $response = $fb->get('/me');
  $userNode = $response->getGraphUser();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  // When Graph returns an error
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}
$graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();


try {
 $response = $fb->post('/wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww/feed', $linkData,       $pageAccessToken);
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
 echo 'Graph returned an error: '.$e->getMessage();
 exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
 echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: '.$e->getMessage();
 exit;
}

$link_mensaje= $graphNode['id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Bueno, me autorespondo yo mismo. Ya he dado con la solución a mi problema
Me sobraba todo el código que obtiene el usuario. Al quitar este código ya me entrega las dos partes del ID (tipo 11681253248727_1170578909669113), la que corresponde a la aplicación (que era la que me entregaba antes y la propia del mensaje. 
    $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($pageAccessToken);
    try {
      $response = $fb->get('/me');
      $userNode = $response->getGraphUser();
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
      // When Graph returns an error
      echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      exit;
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
      // When validation fails or other local issues
      echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      exit;
    }
    $graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();